# Docker + ELK stack taking up more space than it should

Tags: docker, elastic-stack

So I have a docker compose file that looks something like this

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: elasticsearch 
  volumes:
    - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    - ./elasticsearch/config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config
    - ./elasticsearch/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  restart: always
  environment:
    - ES_HEAP_SIZE=1g

logstash:
  build: logstash/
  command: logstash -f /config/logstash.conf
  volumes:
    - ./logstash/config:/config
  ports:
    - "5044:5044"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
  environment:
    - LS_HEAP_SIZE=512m
kibana:
  build: kibana/
  volumes:
    - ./kibana/config/:/opt/kibana/config/
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
```

When doing a check of index size / disk usage there seems to be a bit of misalignment.

```
    [root@~]# curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
    health status index               pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
    yellow open   filebeat-2016.11.17   5   1    3042279            0      1.7gb          1.7gb
    yellow open   filebeat-2016.11.14   5   1    3350057            0      2.1gb          2.1gb
    yellow open   .kibana               1   1          3            0     16.1kb         16.1kb
    yellow open   filebeat-2016.11.16   5   1    1716748            0    972.7mb        972.7mb
    yellow open   filebeat-2016.11.15   5   1    2126918            0      1.5gb          1.5gb
```

What's strange is that this should account for about 6.3gb of space + the images of ELK, which we'll high-ball at 1gb.   Meanwhile the space on disk is a bit closer to 12 - 13gb.

Each day I'm running a custom python script which makes a CURL call to ElasticSearch to drop the oldest index.

I've also noticed that when doing a du -h there's a small misalignment in the ES size of the index vs what du -h reports:  Example--

```
2.2GB /usr/share/docker/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/filebeat-2016.11.14
```

I am using the default logstash template, which doesn't seem to be matching my filebeat config, which may be contributing to above average log sizes.   Can someone help shed some light on what else might be leaking into the file system and eating up space?

Thanks

Comment: Have I done a .... what?

Comment: This post explains the discrepancy between the ES size of the index and what `du -h` reports.   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966452/size-of-an-index-on-the-file-system-in-elasticsearch  

But I'm not sure of what else could be eating up your disk space. Have you tried running `du -h` or better yet `du -a -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr` on a higher level directory to try to find any unexpected large directories?